# SQL Server: view or function contains a self-reference. Views or functions cannot reference themselves directly or indirectly

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to change the date format of a column stored in a view by doing an `ALTER VIEW` statement, but it's not working and I'm not sure why.

My query:

```
 ALTER VIEW v_cust_invoices
 AS
     SELECT 
         FORMAT(INV_DATE,'MM-dd-yy') as INV_DATE
     FROM 
         v_cust_invoices
```

I always get the error

> View or function 'v_cust_invoices' contains a self-reference. Views or functions cannot reference themselves directly or indirectly

I'm trying to change the date format of `INV_DATE` to `mm-dd-yy` (it's currently `yy-mm-dd`). Can someone help me? Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Edit: If I do

```
 ALTER VIEW v_cust_invoices
 AS
     SELECT FORMAT(INV_DATE,'MM-dd-yy') as INV_DATE
     FROM INVOICE
```

instead, it deletes all of the columns except for `INV_DATE`.

View definition:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[v_cust_invoices] AS 
    SELECT 
        CUSTOMER.CUST_NUM, CUST_LNAME,
        CUST_BALANCE, INV_NUM, INV_DATE, INV_AMOUNT 
    FROM 
        CUSTOMER, INVOICE
GO
```

Comment: Drop and recreate the view.  Open it in SQL Enterprise Mgr, or script it as an Alter, modify the type in the definition, and then execute it.  the original view does NOT reference itself, it must reference some other view or a table

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The types of everything is good, I just have something wrong with the query.

Comment: Views only manipulate and produce data from *tables*, where is this view supposed to get the data from ? there is no reference to a table in the view definition.  Look sat the *current* definition of the view, at it's FROM clause.  You will see a reference to a *table* or to some *other* view.

Comment: I did try changing  FROM v_cust_invoices to FROM INVOICE, however it delete all of the columns out of the view except for INV_DATE which could also no longer be selected.

Comment: Post the COMPLETE definition of the `v_cust_invoices` view.  Whatever that is, simply edit the output format of the output column you want to change from whatever it is to `FORMAT(INV_DATE,'MM-dd-yy')`. LEAVE THE REST AS IT IS.

Comment: Do you know how to display the view definition ??

Comment: Yes, sorry. Will edit the original post.

Comment: Edited, added view definition.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change the query so that it does not reference itself.
Look at the current definition of the `v_cust_invoices` view, at its `FROM` clause. You will see a reference to a table or to some other view. replace the last line in your query with the last line below, substituting the name of the table (or other view) this view gets it's data from.

```
ALTER VIEW v_cust_invoices
AS
SELECT FORMAT(INV_DATE,'MM-dd-yy') as INV_DATE, 
    [Plus all the rest of the output columns 
     from CURRENT definition of v_cust_invoices]
FROM [here Put the table or other view that is in current view definition]
```

or, now that op has posted complete view definition:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[v_cust_invoices] AS 
  SELECT FORMAT(INV_DATE,'MM-dd-yy') INV_DATE, 
       CUSTOMER.CUST_NUM, CUST_LNAME,
       CUST_BALANCE, INV_NUM, INV_DTE, INV_AMOUNT 
  FROM CUSTOMER, INVOICE
GO
```